Prove $\varphi$ is $s$-continuous $\iff \varphi$ is $w$-continuous
Suppose $\mathscr{M}$ is a von Neumann algebra. I am following the definitions of $s$-topology and $w$-topology on $\mathscr{M}$ as given here (or here). Using these definitions I want to prove:

For any form $\varphi$ on $\mathscr{M}$, $\varphi$ is $s$-continuous $\iff \varphi$ is $w$-continuous.

I have managed to prove the direction $(\implies)$: For this first note that $s\text{-topology}=so\text{-topology}$ on the unit ball $(\mathscr{M})_1$. Then for a form $\varphi$ on $\mathscr{M}$ we get:
$$
\varphi \text{ is } s\text{-cont. on }\mathscr{M} \implies \varphi \text{ is } so\text{-cont. on }(\mathscr{M})_1 \implies \varphi \text{ is completely additive} \iff \varphi \text{ is }w\text{-cont. on } \mathscr{M}
$$
But I'm stuck on the direction $(\impliedby)$. Suppose $\varphi$ is a $w$-continuous form on $\mathscr{M}$. Let $(x_i) \subset \mathscr{M}$ be a net s.t. $x_i\xrightarrow{s} 0$. We need to show that $\varphi(x_i) \to 0$. But using polar decompositin I got
$$
|\varphi(x_i)| = ||\varphi|(x_iv)| \le |\varphi|(x_ix_i^*)^{1/2} |\varphi|(v^*v)^{1/2}    
$$
Now since $|\varphi|$ is normal and $x_i\xrightarrow{s} 0$, we know $|\varphi|(x_i^*x_i)^{1/2}\to 0$ but NOT necessarily $|\varphi|(x_ix_i^*)^{1/2}\to 0$. What to do at this point? Thanks.

A little bit funny, but you’re actually stuck on what is usually supposed to be the easy direction. Anyway, just use the polar decomposition for $\varphi^\ast$: $\varphi^\ast = R_u|\varphi^\ast|$, so $\varphi = L_{u^\ast}|\varphi^\ast|$. Now just use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Ahh I see. Thanks
